# Run nodejs app that uses Firebird on a Ubuntu 16 Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebird

I developed an API in javascript and nodejs and now I try to run it on an Ubuntu16 Server.
The API run well on my local computer but not on the server. When I start it on the server, I have this error:

> body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option
>   app.js:12:20 module.js:328
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'firebird'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (/root/Serveur/apishopline/app.js:17:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)

I have install Firebird 2.5 , nodejs v4.2.6, python v2.7.12 and npm v3.5.2 on the server.

So I have try to install the firebird module with the command line :

```
sudo npm install firebird
```

But i have this error too:

```
>     /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libfbclient.so when
> searching for -lfbclient
>     /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libfbclient.so when searching for -lfbclient
>     /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../libfbclient.so when searching
> for -lfbclient
>     /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libfbclient.so when searching for -lfbclient
>     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfbclient
>     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>     binding.target.mk:133: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding.node' failed
>     make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding.node] Error 1
>     make: Leaving directory '/root/node_modules/firebird/build'
> gyp ERR! build error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit
> code: 2 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23) gyp ERR!
> stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
> ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-93-generic gyp ERR! command
> "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebird gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6 gyp ERR!
> node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok  npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-93-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "firebird"
> "-g" npm ERR! node v4.2.6 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR! code
> ELIFECYCLE
> 
> npm ERR! firebird@0.1.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit
> status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the firebird@0.1.1 install
> script 'node-gyp rebuild'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest
> version of node.js and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most
> likely a problem with the firebird package, npm ERR! not with npm
> itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
> ERR!     node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! You can get information on how to
> open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs firebird
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm
> ERR!     npm owner ls firebird npm ERR! There is likely additional
> logging output above.
> 
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /root/Serveur/apishopline/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: From the error trace: "Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed." (nodejs 4.2.6 and npm 3.5.2 are relatively old). BTW: Could you reformat all your error messages with code instead of quote formatting, that would make them more readable

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I install the latest version but the problem is on this line: /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/libfbclient.so when searching for -lfbclient

Comment: That error is nowhere to be found in your question. Consider updating it with the current state of errors.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Idid it now

Comment: Your error log still indicates you are still using an old NPM and NodeJS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the -lfbclient library. The current name and version is [libfbclient2](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libfbclient2), therefore create a symklink to libfbclient.

1. look for libfbclient2

   ```
   find /usr/ libfb | grep libfb
   ```
2. go to the directory where libfbclient2 is

   ```
   cd /path/to/lib/
   ```
3. create a symlink in order to allow the script to find lfbclient

   ```
   ln -s libfbclient2.so libfbclient.so
   ```
4. reinstall the npm modeule

   ```
   npm install firebird
   ```